# How to deal with globals in modules?

Tags: python, function, global-variables, python-import

I try to make a non blocking api calls for [OpenWeatherMap](http://www.openweathermap.com/api), but my problem is:

When i was doing tests on the file, and run it, the `global api` was taking effect, but when importing the function, `global` dont work anymore, and `api` dident change: `api = ""`?

Just after declaring the function i put `global api`, and then when I use `print 'The API link is: ' + api` I get the exact `api`, but `global` dident took effect!

Here is the code: https://github.com/abdelouahabb/tornadowm/blob/master/tornadowm.py#L62

What am I doing wrong?

When I import the file:

```
from tornadowm import *
forecast('daily', q='london', lang='fr')
The API link is: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lang=fr&q=london
api
Out[5]: ''
```

When executing the file instead of importing it:

```
runfile('C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/tornadowm.py', wdir='C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages')

forecast('daily', q='london', lang='fr')
The API link is: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lang=fr&q=london

api
Out[8]: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lang=fr&q=london'
```

Edit: here is the code, if the Git got updated:

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
url = ''
response = ''
args = []
link = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/'
api = ''
result = {}
way = ''


def forecast(way, **kwargs):
    global api
    if way in ('weather', 'forecast', 'daily', 'find'):
        if way == 'daily':
            way = 'forecast/daily?'
        else:
            way += '?'
        for i, j in kwargs.iteritems():
            args.append('&{0}={1}'.format(i, j))
        a = ''.join(set(args))
        api = (link + way + a.replace(' ', '+')).replace('?&', '?')
        print 'The API link is: ' + api

        def handle_request(resp):
            global response
            if resp.error:
                print "Error:", resp.error
            else:
                response = resp.body

        http_client.fetch(api, handle_request)
    else:
        print "please put a way: 'weather', 'forecast', 'daily', 'find' "


def get_result():
    global result
    if response.startswith('{'):
        print 'the result is JSON, stored in the variable result'
        result = json.loads(response)

    elif response.startswith('<'):
        print 'the result is XML, parse the result variable to work on the nodes,'
        print 'or, use response to see the raw result'
        result = ET.fromstring(response)

    else:
        print '''Sorry, no valid response, or you used a parameter that is not compatible with the way!\n please check http://www.openweathermap.com/api for more informations''
```

Comment: Why use a global when you're using this variable only in one place? Are you using it somewhere not shown in your code example?

Comment: also, your **args** technically not defined within your `def` when import and should raise an error

Comment: just edited the question, now, as you can see, if i run the file, i get the `global` changed, but when importing it, the `global` is not touched, `python 2.7.9`

Comment: @Abdelouahab for the sake of posterity, try to paste the important part of your code directly in your question next time, because your link could go broken or changed and you want your question to still make sense some years from now for users who will come there from google or similar :)

Comment: @Jivan thank you, i just did it, so in case it is lost, or the git changes, so people will always get it useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the side effect of using `global`.

When you do `from tornadowm import *` your `forecast()` function is, we could say metaphorically, "on its own" and is not "hard-linked" to your global space anymore.

Why? Because any effect you make on your global `api` will "end" with your function, and the definition of `api = ""` in your global space will take precedence.

Also, as a side note, it's not considered a good practice to use `from something import *`. You should do `from tornadowm import forecast` or even better, `import tornadown` and then use `tornadowm.forecast()`.

- **OR**

Even better, I just noticed your `forecast()` function doesn't return anything. Which technically makes it not a `function` anymore, but a `procedure` (a procedure is like a function but it returns nothing, it just "does" stuff).

Instead of using a `global`, you should define `api` in this function and then `return api` from it. Like this:

```
def forecast(blablabla):
    api = "something"
    blablabla
    return api
```

And then

```
import tornadowm
api = tornadown.forecast(something)
```

And you're done.

Comment: we have technically the same answer, but with yours more in details and understandable

Comment: so then, that means to avoid `global` when dealing  with imports?

Comment: when you try to do `from tornadowm import forecast` instead of `*`, what does it say?

Comment: now it worked when importing the module with its method, dident know about this!

Comment: @Jivan, you know what? That's `return api` was actually in my mind too :) haha

Comment: @Anzel I think we should start a company together

Answer (score 2):

Globals are global only to the module they're defined in. So, normally, you would expect `tornadowm.api` to be changed when you call `forecast`, but not `api` in some other namespace.

The `import *` is contributing to your understanding of the problem.  This imports `api` (among other names) into the importing namespace. This means that `api` and `tornadowm.api` initially point to the same object. But these two names are not linked in any way, and so calling `forecast()` changes only `tornadowm.api` and now the two names point to different objects.

To avoid this, don't use `import *`. It is bad practice anyway and this is just one of the reasons. Instead, `import tornadowm` and access the variable in the importing module as `tornadowm.api`.

Comment: ah, i get it now, in the past, i thought using `import *` was only about readability (to know which module we used for this method), and not to have methods collision!

Comment: @Abdelouahab note that those two reasons you point alone are enough to justify not using `global`. But you've just discovered a third reason :)

Comment: and a big reason! i even tried using `list.append()` as a trick, but even that dident help, so it seems that i got a new hidden feature! thank you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is because **global** is coupled within module, by the time you `from tornadowm import *` you have imported the `api` name, but the **global api** won't take any effects within another module.

Comment: ah, so as @jivan said, it is like only the function that is seen, not the globals

Comment: @Abdelouahab, you get it right to some extent. You may actually see kindall's answer, he has explained in a much better details that you should be able to understand how **global** works in Python